# Other options for creating table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, string

I am creating a huge html table using StringBuilder in the code behind, based on various search criterias selected by the user. The logic is complex as I have to create sub heading,  nested tables etc. and it is really hard to maintain or modify. Is there a better way to deal with such kind of problems?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few years ago I was in the same situation. The problem included dynamic columns, subheadings, cells, everything. A typical table would be around 1000 rows and 50 columns (that's 50,000 cells!). The original implementation used a `GridView` and performed horribly. I rewrote the view to use a `Repeater`, a very light-weight looping control, with `Literal` controls. That reigned in a bit of the madness vs. 100% `StringBuilder`. I combined that with a bunch of static methods which returned string representations for standard html bits (kind of like ASP.NET MVC's "html helpers"), as well as keeping the object model completely isolated. It was all very fast (I forget, but I think the way the `Repeater` and `Literal` controls are rendered is directly to the response stream, so performance was comparable to `StringBuilder`, perhaps even better).

Even the above will be complex, and is akin to your own approach. But the key to maintaining sanity is to keep the different pieces separate (object model, html generation, and dynamic binding). It's almost like building your own ad-hoc framework. But for serious jobs like this, you need to get nitty-gritty when confined to web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

All ASP and Html controls are encapsulated in classes. You're interested in the [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx) class (for ASP) and [`HtmlTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the more light-weight, html-only class.

If I had to choose, I'd go for the html one, unless you want to add server-side events to the table.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the built in native ASP.NET Table control

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_table.asp

Answer (score 0):

[GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx), [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx), [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx), [Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx) e&.